# Fail to find files in directory, can not find file

Tags: r, csv, directory

I tried to write my first function and use multiple files, I tried to create a directory

Step1. I create directory: "specdata", I run: `getwd()`

and get *"/Users/wulingqi/Documents/R/coursera"*

Step2. I unzip a zip file and move 332 csv files inside to the "specdata" folder

Step3. I run  `read.csv("1.csv")` but get the error:

*Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '1.csv': No such file or directory*

Step4. I searched on stack, and found this error may because of `/spectdata/1.csv`, which should be  `/spectdata1.csv`

So I tried `read.csv("1.csv",sep = "/")` but get the same error.

Could someone give me some advice about this error? Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be `read.csv("spectdata/1.csv")` since `spectdata` is the directory containing your `.csv`?

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and get the same error. I tried to change working directory: `setwd("~/Documents/R/coursera/specdata")`, and run `dir()`, I could see "1.csv", and write `read.csv("spectdata/1.csv")`, still get the error.

Comment: If you changed your wd to `~/Documents/R/coursera/specdata`, `read.csv("1.csv")` should do the job.

Comment: You have written both  `specdata` and `spectdata`   .  Please verify consistency in your actual situation

Comment: Now it works. Thank you for all advice.

Comment: Can someone please close this question as solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f you changed your wd to ~/Documents/R/coursera/specdata, read.csv("1.csv") should do the job.    From  Martin Gal